# Catastrophic cancellation

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, average, catastrophic-cancellation

I need some informations about algorithms to solve the problem of catastrophic cancellation, or in general to calculate mean and variance of a data stream. For example about Donald Knuth's algorithm or, also, about new algorithms or methods to solve the same problem.

Comment: Could you sketch _what_ this problem is? Also "Donald Knuth's algorithm" is at about the same level of specificity as "that paper by Erdös".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this page](http://www.exampleproblems.com/wiki/index.php/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance). The third algorithm shown is Knuth's. The algorithm is said to be "numerically stable", which implies that it avoids catastrophic cancellation, among other things.

See also [here](http://www.johndcook.com/standard_deviation.html) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance). The algorithm given by Knuth goes back to a 1962 paper by Welford. You will find lots of material if you google "welford mean variance".